# How to populate a value in a row in an R data frame based on values in other rows

Tags: r

Consider an R dataframe as below.

```
Month Parent Child Parent_amt  Child_amt
   1     p1       c1    30          10
   1     p1       c2    30          20
   1     p2       c1    40          15
   1     p2       c2    40          25
   2     p1       c1    60          10
   2     p1       c2    60          50
   2     p2       c1    20          15
   2     p2       c2    20           5
   3     p1       c1    25          (10+10)/(30+60)*25
   3     p1       c2    25          (20+50)/(30+60)*25
```

Given parent_amt 25 for p1 in the last two rows I want to calculate the Child_amt for c1 as the proportion of 25 that is equal to the ratio of the sum of the Child_amt for c1 to the sum of the parent_amt for p1 in all the rows above the last two. I want to do a similar thing for c2. How do I do this? I can't really think of any way in R. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand the structure of your data. I'm not sure it should be organised this way. I have managed to produce the results you wanted using dplyr:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble::tribble(
   ~Month, ~Parent, ~Child, ~Parent_amt,  ~Child_amt,
   1, "p1", "c1", 30, 10,
   1, "p1", "c2", 30, 20,
   1, "p2", "c1", 40, 15,
   1, "p2", "c2", 40, 25,
   2, "p1", "c1", 60, 10,
   2, "p1", "c2", 60, 50,
   2, "p2", "c1", 20, 15,
   2, "p2", "c2", 20, 5,
)

new_df <- df %>%
  dplyr::bind_rows({
    df %>%
      dplyr::group_by(Parent, Child) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(
        Child_amt = sum(Child_amt) / sum(Parent_amt) 
      ) %>%
     dplyr::mutate(Month = 3, Parent_amt = 25, Child_amt = Child_amt * 25)
  })

new_df
```

I've assumed that Parent_amt is preset to 25, and that we are producing Child_amt from the previous combination of Parent_amt and Child_amt as you described

Comment: Thank you. This does not work. I have given the expression for the expected values. Your code does not yield those values.

Comment: I've updated it now. So you can see the step where I derive the new Child_amt value from the previous ones... then the mutate function adds the new month, sets Parent_amt to 25, and then scales Child_amt by 25... is this giving the correct answer now?